# Fancytree lazyLoad: post event

Tags: jquery, events, post, fancytree, jquery-lazyload

I have a Fancytree with the following lazyLoad function:

```
lazyLoad: function (event, data) {
    data.result = {
        url: "/some/url",
        data: { "Id": data.node.key }
    };
},
```

I need to perform some actions on the new nodes once the lazy data has loaded and the new nodes have been displayed. Is there a function that allows me to do this? postLazyLoad() or something similar? I would need to hook into *data.result* to get the keys of the new nodes.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `loadChildren` event:

```
 $("#tree").fancytree({
      ...
      loadChildren: function(event, data) {
        ...
      },
```

Comment: Unfortunately loadChildren doesn't fit the requirement, as it is triggered as the tree is first loaded, as well as when each node is expanded, regardless if it is lazy or not.

Comment: `loadChilren` fires after *new* children  have been added to a parent, including the invisible system root node, but not on every expansion (only when a lazy node is expanded for the first time). If you want to modify the ajax result, you may use the `postProcess` event, but this is triggered *before* rendering the nodes.

Comment: Thanks, I stand corrected :) I'm using `isRoot()` in the `loadChildren` event to ignore the system root node loading, as I only need the event as each lazy node is expanded.

Comment: loadChildren is fired BEFOR the children integreted in DOM. You can change the data of the children, but you can't change the look of the nodes and you can't register events on them.